# C#: Get field/property/method value (which is either string or uint) by name using reflection

Tags: c#, generics, system.reflection

I'm trying to parse some data out of many old assemblies from a 5-year old open source project and have mostly got it working, but the code is extremely verbose.

Edit: Also, I'm, trapped on .Net Framework 3.5

There are two members I'm interested in are named `"Version"` and `"TargetVersion"`.

Until recently the `"Version"` member was a `string` defined in various ways. It's now replaced with a `"ModVersion"` member that grabs from assembly version. Some examples:

```cs
public string Version => "1.4";

public static readonly string Version = "1.8.14";

public const string Version = "2.8";

public static Version ModVersion => typeof(MainClass).Assembly.GetName().Version;
```

The `TargetVersion` member only has two forms: `public static readonly uint` or `public const uint`.

So currently I get the member type, and then have nested `if .. else if ...` for various member types like so:

```cs
                    string dirty = string.Empty;

                    MemberTypes memberType = GetMemberType(mod, "Version");

                    if (memberType == MemberTypes.Property) {
                        Log.Info("It's a property");
                        dirty = mod
                            .GetProperty("Version", PUBLIC_STATIC)
                            .GetValue(mod, null)
                            .ToString();
                    } else if (memberType == MemberTypes.Field) {
                        Log.Info("It's a field");
                        dirty = mod
                            .GetField("Version", PUBLIC_STATIC)
                            .GetValue(mod)
                            .ToString();
                    } else if (memberType == MemberTypes.Method) {
                        Log.Info("It's a method");
                        dirty = mod
                            .GetMethod("Version", PUBLIC_STATIC)
                            .Invoke(null, null)
                            .ToString();
                    } else {
                        Log.Info("Version: Unsupported member type or not found");
                    }
```

And then I've got a similar pile of code for getting the `"TargetVersion"` which is a `uint`. And now I'll need to add something else to get the new `"ModVersion"` in cases where `"Version"` is not found...

Is there any way I can reduce duplication? For example, is it possible to use generics? (I'm still newbie at C#) to avoid duplicating the code for the `string` vs `uint` vs. `Version`? And is there a way to chop down the amount of code that deals with the different member types?

I've seen something like this elsewhere on SO but no idea how to adapt it to my use case:

```
MemberInfo info = type.GetField(memberName) as MemberInfo ??
    type.GetProperty(memberName) as MemberInfo;
```

What I'm ultimately hoping to achieve is something where I can specify a type and member name and just get the value back. Sort of a `bool TryGetMemberValue<T>(Type thing, string memberName, out <T>value)` method.

Hope this question isn't too dumb, I'm still learning the basics :o

Comment: Do you just want to get its value?

Comment: You would still need a manual check since the member can also be a method, which needs to be invoked

Comment: @Michael: Yes, just looking to get the value. The project has been through lots of maintainers and they all had different ways of specifying the version details. I know roughly what the member names are, and for given member name what the value type will be, but the way they are implemented varies from maintainer to maintainer. So I wany to say: Try getting "Version" value first (string), if that's not there get "TargetVersion" (uint), if that's not there get "ModVersion" (Version).

Comment: have you considered `nameof()`

Comment: @Haytam: I think I already have method covered, although not checked it yet.

Comment: @Clint: Ah, I should mention I'm trapped on .Net Framework 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were nearly there, maybe something like this

<sub>***Note** : I have just returned a string. You could pass another generic parameter in if you like and cast the results, however i assume all the types you want to work with will override `ToString`*</sub>

```
public static bool TryGetValue<T>(T instance, string name, out string value)
{
   value = default;

   var member = typeof(T).GetMember(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)
                         .FirstOrDefault();

   if (member == null)return false;

   switch (member.MemberType)
   {
      case MemberTypes.Field:
         value = (member as FieldInfo)?.GetValue(instance).ToString();
         break;
      case MemberTypes.Method:
         value = (member as MethodInfo)?.Invoke(instance, null).ToString();
         break;
      case MemberTypes.Property:
         value = (member as PropertyInfo)?.GetValue(instance).ToString();
         break;
      default:
         return false;
   }

   return true;

}
```

or if you really want the *type* explicitly

```
public static bool TryGetValue<T,T2>(T instance, string name, out string value)
{
   ...

   switch (member.MemberType)
   {
      case MemberTypes.Field:
         value = (T2)(member as FieldInfo)?.GetValue(instance);
      ...
}
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uQE7Mq)

## Update

Here is a version where you give the type, and it spins up an instance to get the instance members, then disposes if it needs to

```
public static T GetValue<T>(object instance , MemberInfo member)
{
   switch (member.MemberType)
   {
      case MemberTypes.Field: return (T)(member as FieldInfo)?.GetValue(instance);
      case MemberTypes.Method: return (T)(member as MethodInfo)?.Invoke(instance, null);
      case MemberTypes.Property: return (T)(member as PropertyInfo)?.GetValue(instance);
      default:return default;
   }
}
 
public static bool TryGetValue<T>(Assembly asm, string className, string name, out T value)
{
   value = default;    
   var type = asm.GetType(className);    
   var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

   try
   {
      var member = type.GetMember(name, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)
                       .FirstOrDefault();

      if (instance == null || member == null) return false;

      value = GetValue<T>(instance, member);
   }
   finally
   {
      (instance as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
   }

   return true;   
}
```

**Usage**

```
Assembly asm = <some assembly>;

if(TryGetValue<uint>(asm, "MyNameSpace.Test1", "TargetVersion", out var out1))
     Console.WriteLine(out1);
```

Comment: That's insanely nice! However, I'm struggling to work out how to get the instance to pass in.

In my previous attempts I have an `Assembly asm` from which I was getting the `Type mod = asm.GetType("SomeNamespace.SomeClass")`. But passing `mod` in as the instance doesn't seem to be working :/

Comment: @Aubergine18 ahh i see, oops, this code is useless for you. 2 secs

Comment: And yes, I'd ideally want to keep the `uint` as `uint` (if I get them as `string` I'll just have to convert back to `uint` anyway).

When I get back strings from `"Version"` I run those through regex to clean them of unwated chars and then use `new Version(cleanedStr)` to turn them in to `Version` instances.

For the `uint` values (there's acually three of them in separate properties/fields) I'd be using `new Version(x, y, z)` ideally.

Comment: @Aubergine18 how are you getting the instance through, i mean you can get a instance member without and instance.. are you using `CreateInstance` or something ? ahh i see, no matter